# Jquery .load not using stylesheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sorry for bad English title, but I'm currently making my ASE and I want dynamic pages. One container and when clicked on a navigation item it will load the pages into the container.

However, if I use jQuery .load, the style is not correct. It seems it doesn't use the stylesheet from either the main page as the content page. I put the stylesheet link on both. I use Bootstrap.

This is my main.php (the main page with the container):

```
            <?php
            include('../includes/global.php');

            ?>
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
                <head>
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                    <meta name="description" content="">
                    <meta name="author" content="">
                    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
                    <title><?php echo Core::getSettings()->getValue('blogname'); ?> ASE - Dashboard</title>
                    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
                    <link href="../styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
                    <link href="../styles/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
                    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
                    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../scripts/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
                    <script src="../scripts/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
                    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="script/ase_main.js"></script>
                    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
                    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
                    <![endif]-->
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><?php echo Core::getSettings()->getValue('blogname'); ?></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                    <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
                                <?php include ('headers/navigator.php'); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main" id="mainContent"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="../scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="../scripts/docs.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="../scripts/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
                </body>
            </html>
```

This is the Dashboard.php (the page dynamically loaded):

```
<link href="../styles/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
<h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>
<div class="row placeholders">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
        <img data-src="../scripts/holder.js/200x200/auto/sky" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
        <h4>Label</h4>
        <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
        <img data-src="../scripts/holder.js/200x200/auto/vine" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
        <h4>Label</h4>
        <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
        <img data-src="../scripts/holder.js/200x200/auto/sky" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
        <h4>Label</h4>
        <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
        <img data-src="../scripts/holder.js/200x200/auto/vine" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
        <h4>Label</h4>
        <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
    </div>
</div>
<h2 class="sub-header">Section title</h2>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Header</th>
                <th>Header</th>
                <th>Header</th>
                <th>Header</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1,001</td>
                <td>Lorem</td>
                <td>ipsum</td>
                <td>dolor</td>
                <td>sit</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,002</td>
                <td>amet</td>
                <td>consectetur</td>
                <td>adipiscing</td>
                <td>elit</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,003</td>
                <td>Integer</td>
                <td>nec</td>
                <td>odio</td>
                <td>Praesent</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,003</td>
                <td>libero</td>
                <td>Sed</td>
                <td>cursus</td>
                <td>ante</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,004</td>
                <td>dapibus</td>
                <td>diam</td>
                <td>Sed</td>
                <td>nisi</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,005</td>
                <td>Nulla</td>
                <td>quis</td>
                <td>sem</td>
                <td>at</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,006</td>
                <td>nibh</td>
                <td>elementum</td>
                <td>imperdiet</td>
                <td>Duis</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,007</td>
                <td>sagittis</td>
                <td>ipsum</td>
                <td>Praesent</td>
                <td>mauris</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,008</td>
                <td>Fusce</td>
                <td>nec</td>
                <td>tellus</td>
                <td>sed</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,009</td>
                <td>augue</td>
                <td>semper</td>
                <td>porta</td>
                <td>Mauris</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,010</td>
                <td>massa</td>
                <td>Vestibulum</td>
                <td>lacinia</td>
                <td>arcu</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,011</td>
                <td>eget</td>
                <td>nulla</td>
                <td>Class</td>
                <td>aptent</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,012</td>
                <td>taciti</td>
                <td>sociosqu</td>
                <td>ad</td>
                <td>litora</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,013</td>
                <td>torquent</td>
                <td>per</td>
                <td>conubia</td>
                <td>nostra</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,014</td>
                <td>per</td>
                <td>inceptos</td>
                <td>himenaeos</td>
                <td>Curabitur</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,015</td>
                <td>sodales</td>
                <td>ligula</td>
                <td>in</td>
                <td>libero</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is the .js (which loads the content):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    console.log($('.nav.nav-sidebar').children());

    $('.navItem').unbind('click').click(changeContentType);
});

function changeContentType() 
{
    $('.navItem').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    $('#mainContent').load($(this).data('content') + '.php', function(){});
}
```

Why doesn't it apply the stylesheet?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's an "ASE"?

Comment: What is the css that isn't being applied?

Comment: I meant housekeeping / staff panel something like that and the CSS not being applied are Bootstrap.min.css and dashboard.css.